# Excel VBA Worksheet.Change not working

Tags: vba, excel, validation, combobox

I have the following code that basically places a combo box over a data validation box (if the cell contains a data validation box) so that the user can still have the autocomplete feature, but the data validation stays in the cell.

```
'=================================================================================================
'From: http://http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal14.html
'Code places combobox over data validation boxes to gain the autocomplete feature

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Cancel As Boolean
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
On Error GoTo errHandler

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("MachineListComboBox")
  On Error Resume Next
If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
  With cboTemp
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
    .Value = ""
  End With
End If

  On Error GoTo errHandler
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    'if the cell contains a data validation list
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'get the data validation formula
    str = Target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
    With cboTemp
      'show the combobox with the list
      .Visible = True
      .Left = Target.Left
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Width = Target.Width + 15
      .Height = Target.Height + 5
      .ListFillRange = str
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
      .Object.Style = 0
        'Object.Style will create a dropdown that will only allow the user to:
        '= 0 ... the user can type in any answer they want, while also getting the dropdown options
        '= 2 ... the user can type but will only get autocomplete options from the dropdown
      End With
    cboTemp.Activate
    'open the drop down list automatically
    Me.MachineListComboBox.DropDown
  End If

exitHandler:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  Resume exitHandler

End Sub

'=================================================================================================
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx
'Optional code to move to next cell if Tab or Enter are pressed
'from code by Ted Lanham
'***NOTE: if KeyDown causes problems, change to KeyUp
'Table with numbers for other keys such as Right Arrow (39)


Private Sub MachineListComboBox_KeyDown(ByVal _
        KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
        ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9 'Tab
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 13 'Enter
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 10).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

However, when I go to use the Worksheet_Change, it doesnt work. I believe it has to do with the combo box overlaying the data validation, because if I do this on a normal data validation cell, it does work... This piece basically says, if they change a data validation box, then a module needs to be called which will update other boxes, based on the first user selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$4" Then

        Call TEST2.Data_Validation_AreaSpecificMachines

    End If

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"However, when I go to use the Worksheet_Change, it doesnt work"* Please define "doesn't work." Event doesn't trigger? Error is thrown? What does it do, and how does that specifically differ from your expectation?

Comment: My apologies- I should have explained: It doesnt throw an error, but basically it's as if it doesnt see the change happen, and does not run the module. I think because the actual change happens in the overlying combobox, and is then reflected in the data validation box, rather than the change happening in the data validation box itself.

Comment: When I place the `If Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$4" Then

        Call TEST2.Data_Validation_AreaSpecificMachines

    End If` within the Worksheet_SelectionChange it does the same thing.

Comment: You may need to call you test2.data_validation_areaspecificmachines macro from the combobox, _Change, _Click or _DropButtonClick event.

Comment: That code strikes me as very inefficient. You don't need to re-create the whole entire combobox everytime the selection changes. Doesn't that make the worksheet sluggish?

Comment: @Mooseman, the ComboBox_Change worked!! Thank you so so much!!

Comment: @Mat's Mug, could you suggest another way? It is somewhat slower, but not terribly noticeable. I really need the autocomplete option but this is essentially me trying to make an excel sheet into its own form thing, so I need the data validation to stay put in certain cells, and be able to be copied and pasted to add more rows.

Comment: I don't believe that the combox changing will fire the worksheet_change event.  Remember to upvote all the help you received.

Comment: @mooseman you should post an answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the combobox change event doesn't trigger the worksheet change event, your  test2.data_validation_areaspecificmachines macro doesn't get call.  You should call your macro from the from the combobox, _Change, _Click or _DropButtonClick event too.